# Can we do Parallel EF LINQ Queries?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, parallel-processing, code-first

I'm creating some WCF service that use EF to query the database for the data that I need. The problem I have at the moment is that I have 2 or more EF LINQ queries which are declared and then executed to bring back my data... but this is in serial. One EF query is issued, and then the next one after that.

Does anyone know of a simple way to issue the queries in parallel? Or am I looking at async /parallel tasks to get the correct behaviour.

I know the DBContext is not thread safe, so I have no problem in declaring multiple contexts if required.

The code so far is as below:

```
using (IMyContext ctx = MyFactory.GetInstance(request.UserId)) {

   Response response = new Response();

   response.customer = ctx.GetCustomerByAccount(request.data.Account);
   response.orders = ctx.GetOrdersByAccount(request.data.Account);
   response.address = ctx.GetDefaultAddressByAccount(request.data.Account);

   return response;
}
```

The GetCustomerByAccount, GetOrdersByAccount, and GetDefaultAddressByAccount code simply looks does a find on the DbSet to get my data.

In case it matters, I'm using EF on Oracle, and using Code First. I have no navigation properties, and no constraints between the tables, so I can't tell EF to load me up the Orders and Address via lazy loading when I query the main Customer record.

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the use of PLINQ.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460699.aspx

[The is also the easy use if Task library.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

which might look a little like the following in your case.

```
using (IMyContext ctx = MyFactory.GetInstance(request.UserId)) {

Response response = new Response();

//response.customer = ctx.GetCustomerByAccount(request.data.Account);
// you will need to get the return type right, but the example is enough no doubt...
var taskCust = new Task<Customer>(() => ctx.GetCustomerByAccount(request.data.Account) );
taskCust.Start();

// similar for 
//   response.orders = ctx.GetOrdersByAccount(request.data.Account);
// response.address = ctx.GetDefaultAddressByAccount(request.data.Account);

Task.WaitAll(taskCust, taskOrders, TaskAddress);

 // fish responses off the tasks and stick in the response structure... See Result property
response.customer =  taskCust.result;
return response;
}
```